# nginx rewrite regex to add / to URL's ignores .pdf requests and adds /

Tags: nginx, regex

On our server we have added `rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`to add a `/` at the end of requested URL's and it works great, however its my understanding that the above regex adds a '/' if the URL does not contain a `whatever.*`

With this in mind can anyone see why it would ignore links contain `.pdf`.

an example url is `https://webaddress.com/lang/course/project/protected/project.pdf`

I can view an image perfectly ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the issue was the regex:

the correct one is `rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`